# Do I need to add Midaslib to my mac program?

Tags: macos, delphi, firemonkey

When I run my program on mac with PAServer, it works.
But when I copy the .App and open it on another mac with no 
PAServer installed, the program doest startup/work.

For my win32 builds I unclude the midalsib.

```
uses
  {$IFDEF WIN32}
  Midaslib,
  {$ENDIF}
```

**EDIT :** Can't really try it now, but this will probably be the solution.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylrqr.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `MidasLib` links the ClientDataSet-related code directly into your executable. Otherwise your executable requires external Midas shared library (`midas.dll` on Windows, `libmidas.dylib` on OSX).

Answer (score 2):

I'd start by following the deployment guide for DataSnap: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Deploying_dbExpress_Database_Applications

For Mac applications that use client data sets you should deploy `libmidas.dylib`.